# saving file to meteor server node js

Tags: node.js, meteor

This Meteor server code attempts to save a file to the server. It is not giving error but I can not find the file anywhere under the folder where the file containing the code is being invoked.
In the `.meteor.versions` file, there is **no** item for `fs`, so not sure if this needs to be installed or a part of node.js as I thought it would.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('fred.html', 'alosh', (err) => {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(`file saved`);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fs is internal in node.js

Use `console.log('Current directory: ' + process.cwd());` to see your current working directory